# My Split() Function in Python is Returning an Incorrect List

Tags: python, python-3.x

My computer science assignment requires me to use to remake the `split()` string method in Python, where `y` is the delimiter and `x` is the string entered by the user.

The code I have done thus far is shown below:

```
def split(x, y = " "):
    list_one = []
    list_two = []

    for char in x:
        if char not in y:
            list_two.append(char)
        else:
            list_one.append(''.join(list_two))
            list_two = []

    return list_one
```

I've encountered problems, though, with the output given by this function. Here are two sample outputs to illustrate:

```
>>> split("babab", "a")
['b', 'b']
>>> split("9*r10*r11", "*r")
['9', '', '10', '']
```

The problems?

1. In `split("babab", "a")`, the last `'b'` is completely absent from the returned `list_one`, and I have no idea why that is.
2. In `split(9*r10*r11", "*r")`, there are empty single quotes in the returned `list_one`; again, I have no idea why they are there. Also, the problem that occurred in 1. happened here, too, with the number `11` missing in the list altogether.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: After the for loop you need check if `list_two` still contains anything. If yes then append it.

Comment: Nobody can explain this to you as well as an interactive visualizer can. Like [this one](http://bit.ly/1vDz35J). When you step through it, it should be obvious why each one is going wrong. (You could also use the built-in debugger, or add a bunch of `print` calls, but a visualizer can be nicer when you really need to see each step, and aren't going to be overwhelmed by way too many of them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two errors are:

1. You don't deal with `list_two` after the loop; and
2. You're checking single characters, which doesn't work correctly when `len(y) > 1`- you should check the start of the string up to the length of `y`.

Given that this is your homework, I think you should take it from there.

Comment: Are you going to tell how to fix it?

Comment: Why would it be my assignment? I didn't ask the question.

Comment: @Barmar ah, sorry, assumed you were the OP; it's *their* assignment

Comment: @jonrsharpe This assignment is individual, not group-based. Either way, thanks for the helpful hints. I'll take it from here.